# How do we change the vertices of the cylinder or segments of bevels afterall?

Tags: bevel

[image]
I wonder how we can modify the vertices of the cylinder or segments of the bevels after we've built it already, or if it is possible to do this? The bevel that I mean here is the manually bevel with scroll wheel, not the bevel modifier.
I remember there is a hotkey to do this in a tutorial video, but I forgot it, if you have any idea about this, please let me know, thanks!

Comment: Modify vertices? Or modifiy the the bevel segments and bevel amount in general? To modify the vertices, go into _Edit Mode_, select vertices and move them or whatever you want to do. To change the amount and segments of beveled edges you either need them to be done with a modifier that was not applied or - if you beveled them manually in _Edit Mode_ - you can only change options while or directly after you beveled them. If you did any other action afterwards, you cannot easily change them anymore.

Comment: Some tutorials said F9 would send out the console of the cylinder, but when I press F9, I got no reaction

Comment: Well, you have to watch those tutorials carefully. `F9` brings out the parameters window of the **last action** you performed. So, add a cylinder and move it with `G`: then your last action was moving and you get the parameters of the movement. Add a cylinder, then add a cube: `F9` brings up the parameters of the cube, not the cylinder. Select the cylinder, go into _Edit Mode_, add a bevel, go back to _Object Mode_: the last action was switching to _Object Mode_. And so on...

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Thanks, what you said really makes sense